# Filling blank in "It became ______ that I was not welcome"

Tags: sentence-construction, adjectives, adverbs

> It became ______ that I was not welcome

There were four words: clear, clearly, certainly, certainty.

I thought that it was "clearly"; I don't know if it was wrong.

Comment: Please wait a day or two before selecting an answer. People may have other useful answers to give - but they may not bother to write you an answer if you've already selected one ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Among the four choices, "*clear*" is the best answer.

Comment: I'm happy to see you branching out into answering a question! But please [edit] to include an explanation of *why* this is correct; answers without explanation do not teach the patterns of the language well.

Answer (score 2):

*Become* is usually followed by either a noun phrase (eg "He became a teacher") or an adjective phrase ("I became angry". "It became clear").

There may be cases where it can be followed by an adverbial complement, but I can't think of any.

So it has to be *clear* or *certain*.

*Certain* is grammatically possible, but does not fit the meaning.

"It became clear that ... " refers to somebody's growing understanding of a situation.

"It became certain that ... " refers to the increasing likelihood or definiteness of a situation; for example "As the results came in it became certain that they were going to win".